# Azure AD, REST APIs, and Postman

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, postman

I'm building an REST API which should be protected by Azure AD. So I have the following OAuth2 items

- Resource Server: My REST API server
- Authorization Server: Azure Active Directory
- Client: Postman
- Resource Owner: me

I've been trying to configure AD using this [blog post](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html#the-azure-ad-part) but then it goes straight to configure a frontend application. In the blog post, the author configured a front end application but during development, the front end is not yet ready, so I will be using Postman

And when I tried using Postman using the Get New Access Token functionality (Grant type is Authorization code with PKCE), it is failing with error `Error: AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests`

Any thoughts on how I can properly test this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's quite hard to say because we don't see any of your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this cogent article on testing Azure AD protected Springboot API: [**Securing a RESTful API using Spring Boot and Microsoft’s Azure Active Directory.**](https://www.digitalonus.com/securing-a-restful-api-using-spring-boot-and-microsofts-azure-active-directory/)

*Here are some screenshots for quick reference on setting up Postman:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works with Postman, but this is an implicit grant. Will this configuration work with a single page app using the authorization code flow with PKCE?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Check this out: https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/performing-azure-ad-oauth2-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce-in-postman/